# Should we mention 45 days work experience to employer?

Tags: job-change, human-resources, india, background-check

I am an IT employee, I've worked totally for 3 organizations until now.

In the second organization I worked only for 45 days while in third organization I completed 3 years. Now I am going to join 4th organization but I have not mentioned 2nd organization name to 4th employer nor in their back ground verification form.

Can it cause for termination if background agency reach out to my 2nd organization details?

Comment: It depends. The answer most likely lies in the form itself. Are you required to mention all employers? Does the form / other documents you signed state the consequences of not providing all information?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't worry about it unless this was for a job requiring a security clearance, or for a job at a financial institution. In what country/state are you located in?

Comment: I am located at India and yes I am going to join a bank. That's why afraid.

Comment: Was the second organization a bank as well? In any case, I really don't know anything about India. Maybe someone else knows.

Comment: What if we answer "yes it's a problem", what will you do about it? Why didn't you mention it to them before (for example, are they a competitor)?

Answer (score 1):

Mentioning 45 days work experience during an interviewer will largely depend on how you spent those 45 days and the auspices under which you left.  If you were terminated for whatever reason, you probably shouldn't mention it.  If, OTOH, you can use it to market and otherwise propel yourself forward, I would totally use it if I were you, especially if you left under your own terms to work on something bigger and/or to to further develop your skill sets.  Bonus: if you have some kind of quantifiable skill set you've attained as a result of a project that you worked on during those 45 days, then all the better.